# splitting large controller method into files

Tags: php, codeigniter

my code is far from DRY and it needs refactored but for the time being i need to split it into files- i have a 300 line controller method that does a lot of api work when called and i just want to put some code into another file so i can read it a bit better without going and re-writing it.

```
if($type == "like"){

    $this->load->helper('posts/likes');

}else{

    $this->load->helper('posts/pic');

}
```

i tried the above method but its treating it like a normal  (would you believe it)-

basically i want to copy and paste the code into another file to clean it up slightly, but the new file should just be an extension of the current method. i dont what to to use php functions (require_once or similar).. can ci not do this?

**to clarify**

I had a  very large controller method- and instead of having 400 lines of code in the one method i want to split it in two files and have the code reside in there. If the conditional passed one file would load into the controller instead of another-

answering my question on how to load files by posting about DRY class methods didnt help my situation- the code should be cleaned- refactored and sorted into a library, i know this but i need a temp fix

**my answer**

The fix was to to lump the code into a subfolder within the controller directory for my posts controller i put the two files in the posts subfolder then used require_once- which worked but i thought ci may have soemthing to load blocks of code.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you're trying to do?

Comment: just to clarify, I did not get the down vote :P

Comment: If you want you can write this above into a simple line: `$this->load->helper("posts/" . ( ($type=="like")?"likes":"pic" ) );` :)

Answer (score 0):

General rule is to keep controller slim.
DRY is the thing you need to take seriously and get ride of it.

Usually I will prepare the controller to call a single model method,
and this model method WILL prepare, and return all the necessary data in correct format back to controller method

so, you can avoid result looping in controller

```
$result = $this->some_source->get_comments($limit=30);
// I don't do loop in controller
$this->load->view("display", $result);

class some_source extends xxx
{
  function get_comments(...)
  {
    // get results
    // loop
    // do necessary massage / format
    // and return
  }
}
```

Comment: the question is about using php from separate files- not about DRY code

Comment: If you don't DRY, you dun have to split!

Comment: you might found me nonsense, skip this if don't fit your taste.